# Where are Sphinx autosummary templates for functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I am building documentation for a project using the Sphinx extension `autosummary`. I would like to make a very slight change to [the default templates that the documentation alludes to](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html#customizing-templates). I was able to copy and modify the templates for `base.rst`, `class.rst`, and `module.rst` as [they are located in the Sphinx folder](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/master/sphinx/ext/autosummary/templates/autosummary).

However, I can't find the templates for `function.rst`, `attribute.rst` and `method.rst`. Where can I find these templates?

Comment: It looks like the templates that you ask about never existed:
https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/commits/master/sphinx/ext/autosummary/templates/autosummary

Comment: Interesting. I suppose I'll have to write the rst files from scratch then. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comment at https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1879#issuecomment-618529636

> Indeed, Sphinx does not have function.rst. But it's not a problem. You
>   can change the template for functions by putting function.rst in your
>   template directory.
>
> If you need an example of the file, please copy base.rst to your local
>   and modify it. Sphinx uses it as a fallback if function.rst not found.